# ShipWire on wpcommerce

Tags: wordpress, ecommerce

I found in wp-commerce the words "Shipware" ...what does it means?

In addition, Where i can find videos or video tutorials/course of cms and plugins for e-commerce? Like Magento, etc. wp-commerce.?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you mean the [wp-ecommerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) plugin.

It supports integration with a service called [ShipWire](http://www.shipwire.com/), so it's perfectly natural to find it's name in the code and nothing to worry about.

Try [searching for wp-eCommerce videos on youtube](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&site=webhp&q=wp-e%20commerce%20youtube&oq=wp-e%20commerce%20youtube&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...1143420l1150480l0l1150727l16l14l2l0l0l0l167l1058l13j1l16l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=4cef2516941062d9&ix=sea&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=955) for the tutorials, there are many.

Comment: ah ok,but yes: wp-ecommerce for wordpress! For video course and similar I'm searching video training like lyndadatcom and similar....P.S: i'm italian from Palermo..i supposed that shipwire is for international service.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) from WooThemes it's a great ecommerce plugin from IMHO the best WordPress theme developers

Answer (score 0):

shipwire is a warehousing, packaging  and delivery service for online retailers. You can use it with WP e-Commerce. So the code is nothing to worry about.
woocommerce is an excellent e-commerce plugin as well. As of April 2012 there is still no shipwire plugin for woocommerce